# mysql_fetch_assoc($query)

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently getting this error when using `mysql_fetch_assoc($query);`

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a6461923/public_html/index.html on line 111
```

Here is my query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$encripted_password'");
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using mysqli_* or PDOs.

Comment: Please use the search function. This question has been answer time and time again.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Read up at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 6):

> My query is not working…

Steps before asking this question (yet again):

1. Verify your connection to the database.
2. Ensure there is not an error in your query.

You can do this by:

- Connecting to your database outside of PHP **with the same credentials used in your code**.
- Outputting your query (`echo $query;`) then running it against the database directly (such as through PHPMyAdmin or mysql CLI):
- Use functions like [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) in your code.

Some additional tips about common PHP/MySQL programming:

- Read up on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).
- Familiarize yourself on when to escape and quote [literal values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/literals.html) in MySQL.
- Be mindful not to prematurely close your MySQL connection. PHP will actually do so automatically at the end of the script.
- As commented by **Jared**, You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), instead of the [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) MySQL extension.
- Also look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 1):

This probably means the query in `mysql_query()` went wrong. PHP says the error is in `mysql_fetch_assoc()` because there is where it tries to read the query's result. And if the result is not a valid resultset, then a Warning is thrown.

Try something like `die($query);` after you build up the `$query` string to see if anything is wrong (missing variables, happens for everyone once).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run something like the following:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) for a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual. `mysql_fetch_assoc` does not take a string argument. It takes a resource which you get from passing a query to `mysql_query`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php